# Postgres: Find row(s) with Maximum value

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

Using Postgres with the following table (Sensor_data):

```
    _id    |       value       |       createdAt        |         updatedAt          | SensorId

 328545721 | {"value":"12.40"} | 2020-05-08 21:25:55+00 | 2020-05-08 21:26:06.575+00 |      644
 328542532 | {"value":"12.41"} | 2020-05-08 21:20:55+00 | 2020-05-08 21:21:03.485+00 |      644
 328539226 | {"value":"12.38"} | 2020-05-08 21:15:55+00 | 2020-05-08 21:16:02.068+00 |      644
 328536044 | {"value":"12.40"} | 2020-05-08 21:10:55+00 | 2020-05-08 21:10:56.573+00 |      644
 328533180 | {"value":"12.38"} | 2020-05-08 21:05:55+00 | 2020-05-08 21:06:08.519+00 |      644
 328530133 | {"value":"12.36"} | 2020-05-08 21:00:55+00 | 2020-05-08 21:01:03.808+00 |      644
 328524018 | {"value":"12.33"} | 2020-05-08 20:50:55+00 | 2020-05-08 20:50:59.278+00 |      644
 328520823 | {"value":"12.27"} | 2020-05-08 20:45:55+00 | 2020-05-08 20:45:56.882+00 |      644
 328517813 | {"value":"12.22"} | 2020-05-08 20:40:55+00 | 2020-05-08 20:41:09.067+00 |      644
 328514598 | {"value":"12.24"} | 2020-05-08 20:35:55+00 | 2020-05-08 20:36:06.379+00 |      644
```

I want to query for the maximum value and return the updatedAt time for that value.

I can issue the following query:

```
select MAX((value ->> 'value')::float)  from "Sensor_data";
```

And get the following result:

```
max
12.41
(1 row)
```

but how can i get the updatedAt time with this?

If I issue:
select "updatedAt", MAX((value ->> 'value')::float)  from "Sensor_data";

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "Sensor_data.updatedAt" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: select "updatedAt", MAX((value ->> 'value')::float)  from "S...
```

What do I need to make this query, and if the is more than one max value (ie 12.41) will it return more than 1 row?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order by`:

```
select sd.*
from sensor_data sd
order by (value ->> 'value')::float desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow top ties, then sorting is not good enough, since Postgres does not support `with ties` with `limit`.

You can use window functions instead:

```
select (value ->> 'value')::numeric max_value, updatedAt
from (
    select 
        sd.*,
        rank() over(order by (value ->> 'value')::numeric desc) rn
    from sensor_data sd
) t
where rn = 1
```